$X$ locally compact and regular; for every $x$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $cl(U)$ is compact

If $X$ is locally compact and regular; then for every $x \in X$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $cl(U)$ is compact

Let $x \in X$ and $K$ compact neighborhood of $x$, then let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $V \subset K^{\circ}$, then $K \cap V^C$ is closed as $K$ is closed as $X$ is Hausdorff, so by regularity of $X$, there exist $O; O_{x}$ respective disjoint open neighborhoods of $K \cap V^C$ and $x$, so $U=O_x \cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $cl(U)$ is a closed subset of the compact $K$ and then it's also compact as it's asubspace of $K$.
Is this argument valid? If we drop Hausdorfness, do we still get the same conclusion?

For your question 1: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. For your question 2: what is your definition of local compactness for a non-Hausdorff space?

Your proof is correct but overcomplicated. $O$ is not used. In a Hausdorff space, regularity is useless. Just take $U=V$.
